# Как мне правильно прописать правило RewriteRule для такого условия?

Tags: .htaccess

Есть `url` вида
`site.ru/tovar/semena-ovoschey/semena-arbuza/vostochnyj-ornament`.
Как мне правильно прописать правило `RewriteRule`, чтобы получить
`site.ru/semena-ovoschey/semena-arbuza/vostochnyj-ornament`?

Пробовал так:

```
RewriteRule ^tovar/(.*)$ $1 [R=301, L]
```

Но это правило не работает!

Comment: цель-то какая, перепись или редирект?

Comment: Ваш редирект прекрасно работает. Можно проверить [здесь](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

Ваш урл: `http://site.ru/tovar/semena-ovoschey/semena-arbuza/vostochnyj-ornament`

Правило: 

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^tovar/(.*)$ $1 [R=301, L]

Возможно, у Вас вышестоящие правила неверны.